# Option cmyk for xcolor package does not produce a CMYK PDF

Tags: pdf, color

I am trying to produce a CMYK PDF file to pass onto a printshop.

When I use the [cmyk] option for the xcolor package, the colours in the resulting PDF do look muted and less vibrant as is the case with the CMYK colorspace. For example,

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\fontsize{24}{28}\selectfont A}
\end{document}
```

when processed by pdflatex produces a PDF file that appears onscreen like a muted, darkish CMYK colorspace document, but when I run ImageMagick's `identify` command on the PDF using

```
identify -verbose cmyk.pdf | grep Colorspace
```

I get

```
Colorspace: RGB
```

Surely the PDF uses only one of CMYK or RGB for colour. How can I reliably tell which?

Also, if it is indeed an RGB PDF why does it appear so different from the version I get if the line

```
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
```

is replaced by

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/pdf-colour-model-and-latex has a lot to say about color and PDF.

Comment: The option `[cmyk]` causes `xcolor` to automatically transfrom RGB colors to cmyk (unless it already knows the result), doesn't it? If so: the conversion RGB -> cmyk in xcolor is acceptable, but it could be better. Ah: it is mentioned in @ChristianLindig's link: "which are not very sophisticated -- compare them to the formulas in 10.3 of the PDF spec, with BG(k) and UCR(k) functions, etc"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With using `\pdfcompresslevel=0` for PDFTeX or with `\pdfvariable compresslevel` for LuaTeX I'll get the pdf with no compressed streams and can see what happens inside the pdf.

With the cmyk option I get:

```
stream
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
1 1 0 0 k 1 1 0 0 K
BT
/F15 24.7871 Tf 91.925 752.955 Td [(A)]TJ
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
0 0 0 1 k 0 0 0 1 K
ET
endstream
```

and with the rgb option:

```
stream
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
0 g 0 G
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG
BT
/F15 24.7871 Tf 91.925 752.955 Td [(A)]TJ
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
0 0 0 rg 0 0 0 RG
ET
endstream
```

which is what I would expect, a correct color setting. But printing a RGB color is not the same as printing a CMYK color ...

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: `\pdfcompresslevel=0`

Comment: If you're using xelatex, use `\special{dvipdfmx:config z 0}` instead.

Answer (score 20):

There's not really such a thing as a 'CMYK PDF' or an 'RGB PDF'. PDFs can contain objects coloured in RGB and CMYK (and many other) colour spaces. See [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/pdf-colour-model-and-latex/9973#9973) for some details. So your statement "Surely the PDF uses only one of CMYK or RGB for colour." is wrong, and it's unclear to me on what basis "identify -verbose" is deciding that it is RGB. Maybe the colorspace just defaults to RGB, even for formats where that doesn't make sense?

As for your question: "How can I reliably tell which?", in addition to @Herbert's suggestion to look at the uncompressed PDF stream (if that means anything to you) you can use Adobe Acrobat Professional has various tools to see which colour spaces are being used and where. An "Output preview" tool; a "Preflight" tool; a "convert colors" tool; etc.

Comment: Thank you for setting me right. Is there a Linux-friendly software package to do what Adobe Acrobat Professional does above? Thanks.

Comment: +1---I just ran `identify` on a PDF created with ConTeXt using only CMYK colors and got `Colorspace: RGB` as well. Makes me suspect ImageMagick isn't telling the whole story.

Comment: identify (or for that matter ImageMagic) does not properly identify the color space of a PDF file -- even if the PDF file uses only one color space. It converts the PDF to an RGB image and then reports the color-space of that image (which is obviously RGB). The problem has been reported to ImageMagic developers, but it is not taken very seriously by any of them -- so it is not likely to get fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I add the same problem with a LaTeX file.

I wanted to obtain a cmyk PDF file by using `\includepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` but my document was in RGB.

So, since I insert a picture in CMYK color format, the PDF file is in CMYK.

I think if you use coloration for your text, you must add the `cmyk` option.

For example `\definecolor{red}{rgb}{This is text RGB}`

For example `\definecolor{red}{cmyk}{This is text CMYK}`

CMYK does not run if you don't use it.

If all you document is in RGB, your PDF file will be in RGB.

If you insert one mention of `cmyk` in your code, like in the example, your PDF file will be in CMYK.

Good luck.