# Using Pantone/Spot Colors in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

It is possible to use `pantone` color in `XeLaTeX`. I have found only PdfLaTeX in [Using Pantone/spot colors and TikZ together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141245/using-pantone-spot-colors-and-tikz-together). I have both `CMYK` and `Pantone` color and must use `XeLaTeX` because many `OTF` Fonts are used in my book. How to do?

Comment: Related [XeLaTeX and TikZ - how do I ensure my PDFs are using the CMYK color model?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125028/)

Comment: @percusse: I have asked how to use `pantone` colors in XeLaTeX. Provide link is about `CMYK` color.

Comment: There has been recently a message about spotcolor on the xetex list: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-July/025384.html

Comment: *Both CMYK and Pantone*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [xespotcolor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xespotcolor) package. You need the latest version of xdvipdfm-x.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit and post a MWE?

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

`LuaLaTeX` and `xspotcolor` don't work a the moment but `XeLaTeX` and `xespotcolor` still do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xespotcolor}
\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor     {PANTONE}  {PANTONE3035PC} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3035\SpotSpace PC} {1 0 0.05 0.72}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}
\definecolor{PANTONE3035PC}  {spotcolor} {PANTONE3035PC,1.0}
\definecolor{PANTONE3035PCA} {spotcolor} {PANTONE3035PC,0.5}
\definecolor{grey}           {gray}      {0.5}

\begin{document}

Examples:

\begin{itemize}
  \item This is not Pantone
  \item \textcolor{PANTONE3035PC}{This is PANTONE 3035 PC}
  \item \textcolor{PANTONE3035PCA}{This is PANTONE 3035 PCA}
  \item \textcolor{grey}{grey}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`LuaLaTeX` works with [`xspotcolor`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/xspotcolor.dtx) and you can use OpenType fonts. Maybe you should consider using it instead of `XeLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[autodefine]{xspotcolor}
\NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}
\AddSpotColor{PANTONE} {PANTONE3035PC} {PANTONE\SpotSpace 3035\SpotSpace PC} {1 0 0.05 0.72}
\definecolor{PANTONE3035PCA}{spotcolor}{PANTONE3035PC,.5}
\definecolor{grey}{gray}{0.5}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\SetPageColorSpace{PANTONE}

Examples:

\begin{itemize}
  \item this text is not Pantone
  \item \textcolor{PANTONE3035PC}{dark blue}
  \item \textcolor{PANTONE3035PCA}{light blue}
  \item \textcolor{grey}{grey}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This same example works just fine with xelatex! The only difference is that one has to use the xespotcolor package. In addition, I am working on a version that will work just fine with the xcolor conventions.

Comment: @ApostolosSyropoulos The example does not seem to work, even after the change to "xespotcolor" as you mentioned, on either TL2016 or TL2017. Did anything change?

Comment: `xspotcolor` doesn't work with anymore, but `xespotcolor` still does. I will update my answer.