# \includegraphics PDF, color problem

Tags: graphics, color, pdf, transparency

I'm using `pdflatex`, and use `\includegraphics` to include content of figures from PDF. PDF are exported from InkScape.

```
\begin{figure} [!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{fig/SUSAN.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Included PDF or source SVG has same colors. Green has always RGB value (0, 255, 0). Problem occurs when I include this files from LaTeX. In output PDF on some pages colorspace is darker. Even same image on other page has different colourity.

My PDF http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xzamaz00/smutny_smajlik.pdf . As you can see on page 7 (11 in PDF) USAN areas are bright green, but then on page 5 (9 in PDF) are green points on corners more darker.

Comment: Could be a RGB versus CMYK color model issue. Try it again after loading the `xcolor` package with the `cmyk` option. If you get an option clash replace it with `\PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}`. Are you using any form of transparency in your document?

Comment: The question [PDF colour model and LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/pdf-colour-model-and-latex) might give some general insight about color model in LaTeX. The last section of the answer mentions InkScape and CMYK and links to the online article ["Inkscape Does Support CMYK"](http://codewideopen.blogspot.com/2010/10/inkscape-does-support-cmyk.html) which seems to be relevant here.

Comment: yes, in some included PDF is used transparency.

Comment: Use a different viewer than Adobe Reader (PDF-X-change viewer does not have this problem) or add `\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` to the preamble of your document. This will make Adobe Reader use the RGB rendering model for pages with transparency.

Comment: @Martin: I am facing the same problem with a PDF I try to include in a xetex-compiled document. However, the `\pdfpageattr` attribute causes compilation errors in xelatex (with the xdvipdfmx driver).

Comment: You need to use `\special{pdf: [...stuff...]}`. See The dvipdfm manual `dvipdfm.pdf` for the precise syntax of `[...stuff...]`.

Comment: @Martin: I'll try that, but I've managed to fix the problem by converting the image pdf to PDF 1.3 format. I started a separate question about this (because my problem is with xetex, and not pdflatex): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29523/inkscape-pdf-includegraphics-xelatex-changed-colors

Answer (score 21):

Hey I had the same problem with my Lyx docment using pdflatex.  I simply copied the line from Martin Heller, `\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}` and now my images containing transparency are correctly displayed in the final PDF:)

Comment: I tried this but the file still prints the page with included PNG in bold

Answer (score 9):

As Martin Heller already points out, this is probably a transparency issue: Your PDF may use page groups, [which need special treatment in pdftex/luatex to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78020/5763). This *should* be fixed in pdfTeX since 1.40.6, but might fail in luatex - and I don't know about XeTeX. Martin's solution should work with pdftex/luatex.

Comment: I've read before that this type of problem has been fixed in pdftex, but I'm curious about *how* it was fixed. Are you able to point me to the changeset/patch that introduced the fix?

Comment: You'd have to check the changes between 1.40.5 and 1.40.6.
The solution is adding the `/Group` as explained by Martin Heller above if needed (that is if an included PDF has a `/Group` key or a png has transparency). The synthesized `/Group` kicks the transparency mechanism of Adobe Reader.

Comment: The bug was later re-introduced and re-fixed, see this [bug report](http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4326&group_id=106&atid=493)

Answer (score 5):

For XeLaTeX, this problem also occurs and can be fixed by running a small program [XeLaTeX-FixRGB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xelatexfixrgb/) on the resulting PDF.

Comment: There is easier fix, see [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60315/text-appearing-bold-on-some-pages-with-images), just add that code to your preamble.