# Multiple PDFs with page group included in a single page warning

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, warnings, transparency

I updated TeX Live to the Ubuntu Quantal version (2012.20120611-4) and I suddenly got this warning:

> PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page

This is a minimal example for which I get the warning:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics{image1}

  \includegraphics{image2}
\end{document}
```

Both images have been produced by the export PDF feature of Inkscape and contain simple line drawings (no fancy stuff).

I have been looking on the Internet, but only found others with this problem and did not found any solutions:

- In the [Latex user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/latexusersgroup/LrlwmFdhYVQ/xTPkwT7ZgogJ) they did not seem to understand/recognise the problem. And told the OP to go to the MikTeX groups, but it is not a MiKTeX specific problem as it is also happening with TeX Live and other distributions.
- At [gmane.comp.tex.pdftex](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pdftex/5108) they were looking into the use (and versions) of MS Office products. Also not the cause as I am not using MS Office to produce PDFs.

During my search if found the PDFTeX code ([pdftoepdf.cc](http://fossies.org/dox/texlive-20120701-source/pdftexdir_2pdftoepdf_8cc_source.html)) that spawns this warning, maybe it is of some help in understanding what is happening?

```cpp
if (pdfpagegroupval == 0) { 
    // another pdf with page group was included earlier on the same page;
    // copy the Group entry as is
    pdftex_warn("PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page");
    pdf_newline();
    pdf_puts("/Group ");
    copyObject(&dictObj);
} else {
    // write Group dict as a separate object, since the Page dict also refers to it
    pageDict->lookup((char *) "Group", &dictObj);
    if (!dictObj->isDict())
        pdftex_fail("PDF inclusion: /Group dict missing");
    writeSepGroup = true;
    initDictFromDict(groupDict, page->getGroup());
    pdf_printf("/Group %d 0 R\n", pdfpagegroupval);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happening, whether it is serious and how I could get rid of these warnings?

Comment: "*I have been looking on the Internet, but only found others with this problem."* Some links could be useful.

Comment: @lockstep sorry I forgot. I have updated my question showing the two of this discussions going nowhere.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is also reported in a [german forum mrunix.de](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=73546). It might be a bug in the tex distribution (pdftex). The problem happens only when you include multiple pdf pages, created in a specific manner (e.g. by MS Office products), in a single page.

**Solution:**
Convert pdf files into ps and then back to pdf using Ghostscript, then the warning will go away (pdf2ps -> ps2pdf). This conversion probably removes the "page group" information from pdf files. (Caveat: This renders your pdf and some text might not be selectable or searchable any more.)

Editing the colorspace of pdf files with ghostscript also resolves the issue (if there is no multiple pages in the pdf file):

```
gs -o fixed-image.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB 
   -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB original-image.pdf
```

CMYK conversion if RGB does not work for you:

```
gs -o fixed-image.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/CMYK 
   -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK original-image.pdf
```

**P.S.** Some programs generate "page group"s in pdf files; for example when you impose different images/objects in illustrator or inkscape. It seesm that pdftex is unable to handle multiple page groups in a single output page. The reason might be that each page groups specifies a different color space or transparency space.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, it works. Minor disadvantage of `pdf2ps -> ps2pdf`: the text in my PDF figures is not text anymore (ie it is not selectable), so I need to go and find another solution to remove the 'page groups'

Comment: Your ghostscript conversion method works better! Thanks again

Comment: Your `gs` command entirely screwed up my PDF images.

Comment: @Dominique, What happened to your images? The command works for me. You may cosnider converting to another colorspace if RGB does not work for you.

Comment: converting to .ps will rasterise anything with transparency, so not an option for many .pdfs

Comment: Not all conversion to .ps will rasterize.  The command line tools I know unfortunately do that, but Acroread does not.  So  open the file in acroread and use the Print function to print to an eps file. To preserve the bounding box click "Choose paper source by PDF page size" in the dialogue, and choose the right orientation for the figure's aspect ratio. Once saved, you'll have an EPS that converts to PDF sharply.

Comment: On **Windows** you can also use **Adobe Acrobat** and print the generated file with Adobe PDF using the properties in ``"Page Size & Handling" -> "Size"``: ``[x] Actual size`` and ``[x] Choose paper source by PDF page size`` and ``[x] Use custom paper size when needed`` then the warning will go away (if the new pdf is used): [print dialog](http://r38i.imgup.net/Acrobat2986.png)

Answer (score 160):

PDF has a feature called "Page Groups" ([PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), section 11.4.7). These descibe transparency effects between top-level objects on one page. When pdfTeX (or LuaTeX or XeTeX) includes a page from a PDF, it converts all pages into "Form XObjects" (section 8.10.1). pdfTeX also converts the Page Groups into `/Group` entries of the XObjects.

The problem now is that Adobe products need also a `/Group` entry (whose content should not matter) in the `/Page` object which contains these XObjects to correctly render transparency (this is just needed to select the right rendering engine; the transparency information for the included pages should be taken from these included pages).

pdfTeX will either use the first `/Group` it encounters when including PDFs or synthesize one when including PNGs with transparency. **The warning** is triggered when multiple Page Groups are encountered on one page (since the engine will then use the first one encountered and this may not be the "correct" one) and **can probably be ignored**. Of course this should be described somewhere in the pdfTeX documentation...

---

*Update 2016-03-30*:

Since version 1.40.15 (TeXlive 2014) pdfTeX has a parameter `\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup`

> Ordinarily, pdfTeX gives a warning when more than one included pdf
>   file has a so-called “page group object” (`/Group`), because only one
>   can “win” — that is, be propagated to the page level. Usually the page
>   groups are identical, but when they are not, the result is
>   unpredictable. It would be ideal if pdfTeX in fact detected whether
>   the page groups were the same and only gave the warning in the
>   problematic case; unfortunately, this is not easy (a patch would be
>   welcome). Nevertheless, often one observes that there is no actual
>   problem. Then seeing the warnings on every run is just noise, and can
>   be suppressed by setting this parameter to a positive number.

So by adding `\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1` to the top of your file you can suppress this warning.

Comment: Just to clarify: this means you can resolve this by putting `\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1` at the top of your file.

Comment: I frequently encounter this warning using the externalization feature from `tikz` where the `tikzpicture` contains `PNGs`. Your explanation and answer is extremely helpful to avoid hundreds of useless warning (in my application case).

Comment: Now we’ve collectively figured out what PDF page groups are (and, tl;dr, that they have to go from **any and all** included PDFs so `pdf{,la}tex` can set the correct ones), I wish there was an option to warn if _any_ included PDF contains one. The default only triggers if at least two do…

Answer (score 21):

[Martin Schröder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78020) has done a wonderful job of explaining the underlying cause, so I won’t repeat that here.  Other than telling pdfLaTeX to shut up, the solution would be to **remove/strip the page groups from the PDF inputs**.  However, all the proposed solutions seem to suffer from one of these problems:

- **Lossy**: Ghostscript-related solutions apparently rasterize the PDF file, which defeats the whole point of using PDF figures!  I’m very picky when it comes to image quality, so this direction is no-go.
- **Fragile**: Naively doing a find-and-replace (i.e. `sed`) to fix a PDF file is probably not a good idea.  This could corrupt a PDF file.

Turns out there’s this neat open-source tool called [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.html), which can “unpack” PDF files into a regular, quasi-textual format, affectionately named “QDF”.  After running this tool, it was really easy to identify the page group inside the QDF file using a plain text editor.  A fragment is shown below:

```
%% Page 1
%% Original object ID: 5 0
4 0 obj
<<
  /Contents 5 0 R
  /Group <<
    /CS /DeviceRGB
    /I true
    /S /Transparency
    /Type /Group
  >>
  /MediaBox [
    0
    0
    460.799988
    345.600006
  ]
  /Parent 3 0 R
  /Resources 7 0 R
  /Type /Page
>>
```

Mine was created in Inkscape.  Yours may be a bit different.  Notice the `/Group << … >>` dictionary.  This is what needs to be removed.  This can be automated using a Python script:

```
import re, sys

stdin = getattr(sys.stdin, "buffer", sys.stdin)
stdout = getattr(sys.stdout, "buffer", sys.stdout)
stderr = getattr(sys.stderr, "buffer", sys.stderr)

page_group = None
for line in stdin:
    if page_group is None:
        if line.rstrip() == b"  /Group <<":
            page_group = [line]
        else:
            stdout.write(line)
    else:
        page_group.append(line)
        if line.rstrip() == b"  >>":
            break
else:
    if page_group:
        stdout.write(b"".join(page_group))
        page_group = None
for line in stdin:
    stdout.write(line)
stdout.flush()

if page_group:
    stderr.write(b"".join(page_group))
else:
    stderr.write(b"note: did not find page group\n")
```

Save that script to, say, `strip_page_group.py` and then chain all the commands together:

```
qpdf --qdf input.pdf - | python strip_page_group.py | fix-qdf >output.pdf
```

Note 1: Make sure the output filename (`output.pdf`) is different from the input filename (`input.pdf`) or you’ll lose the PDF file entirely!

Note 2: If you need deterministic output, supply `qpdf` with the `--deterministic-id` option.

Comment: Good idea. Lacking `qpdf`, I came to use `sed -i 's-/Group << /CS /DeviceRGB /S /Transparency /Type /Group >>-                                                         -' my.pdf` (adapt number spaces to maintain file size).

Comment: Or even simpler: `sed '/^ \+\/Group <<$/,/^ \+>>$/d'` (assuming there are no other `/Group` dictionaries in the file - I don't know if that's a safe assumption in general). Honestly, the Python script in this answer is much more complicated than a program for this task needs to be. Great answer otherwise, though!

Answer (score 11):

Following the `pdf2ps -> ps2pdf` advice from a previous answer, this is how I solved the issue. I browsed to the folder where my pdf images are located, used `find` to get all filenames, performed both transformations and deleted the temporary `ps` file.

In short (specific to Bash because of `${f%.*}`):

```bash
for f in $(find . -type f  -name "*.pdf"); do \
  echo $f; \
  pdf2ps $f ${f%.*}.ps; \
  ps2pdf ${f%.*}.ps $f; \
  rm -f ${f%.*}.ps; \
done
```

Answer (score 10):

Additional Info / Workaround for MS Office Users: I have been using pdfLaTeX with PDFs generated from Visio for years. I just reinstalled my PC and then I got the warning - but only for NEWLY saved PDFs, not for the old ones. Therefore I looked for PDF options in Visio: If you tell Visio to generate PDF/A compatible PDFs, the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 7):

Another additional info for Adobe Illustrator users: select "Acrobat 4 (PDF 1.3)" Compatibility when saving the PDF. Then the warning will disappear.

Comment: Likewise, [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/184288/how-to-convert-a-pdf-document-to-an-older-version) tells how to do this with ghostscript. Specifically, `gswin64.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf`

Comment: The ghostscript approach worked great for me, eventhough it also worked with compatibility level 1.4, which had the advantage of not rasterizing some of the vectorgraphics in my pdf like 1.3 did

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the issue is not always as harmless as stated in previous comments. I have a file (about 50 pages) with about 70 little sketches (typically 15mm x 8mm, all of them images.pdf), up to 8 sketches on one page. When the warning "multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page" appeared, 5 pages got completely black in the output pdf file, with the Acrobat Reader returning an error message. The remaining 45 visible pages were displayed correctly, including the sketches. With shifting some sketches to other places, other pages got black, with no clear relation between certain images and blackened pages discernible. After I opened all images with GSView, applied File>Converte>pdfwrite with Properties>Compatibility/Level 1.2, both the warnings and the black pages disappeared, and everything is fine now.

Remark: The problem turned up when I started with a new TexLive installation under Windows 8.1 on a new computer. There was no problem with the self-same images.pdf with an older TexLive installation under Windows XP on my old computer. When I viewed the dammaged pdf files with Acrobat Reader on the old computer, they were dammaged as well. When I viewed the pdf output file from the old computer with Arobat Reader on the new computer, everything was fine. Thus obviously the new Techlive is handling images.pdf different than the old TexLive did.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when including PDF figures generated with inkscape (original EPS plot from gnuplot with a PNG overlay with transparency) into a document compiled with pdflatex (from TeX Live 2013 distro). The bad thing was that the resulting PDF document could not be read by some viewers (including acroread 9.5.5).

My **solution** was to use [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) to "linearize" the output of pdflatex,

```
qpdf --linearize corrupted.pdf working.pdf
```

This does not prevent pdflatex from issuing the warnings but at least you get a working document.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using pdf2ps or ghostscript (which both introduced some errors in my pdfs, e.g. missing lines), I just removed the Group information from the PDF with

```
sed -i 's/\/Group.*R//g' file.pdf
```

I don't know if this could introduce any problems, but in my case, with only single-paged libreoffice-exported images, it works well.

Comment: Thank you! 
I edited the regex to include the 'R', which happens to appear on those useless page groups, but not in real groups - at least in libreoffice PDFs. 
If someone would look further into this, I'm sure a Method can be found which securely deletes only the page group information in all PDFs.

Comment: I have the same problem but only `/Group >>` followed by a short section. So this regex cannot help.

Comment: Sorry, this is dangerous advice. It would be nice if you could just delete text from a PDF file but you can't -- there are internal pointers that get corrupted, because they depend on the exactly location of the various elements in the file.  So this answer is best deleted.

Comment: Replace the group by the appropriate number of spaces to maintain targets of internal pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found: Somewhere at the beginning the PDFs contain a group which defines the contents of the page. For a ghostscript generated PDF it looks like this:

```
5 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox [0 0 172.8 201.6]
/Rotate 0/Parent 3 0 R
/Group 4 0 R
/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF /Text]
/ExtGState 104 0 R
/XObject 105 0 R
/Font 106 0 R
>>
/Contents 6 0 R
>>
```

The line `/Group 4 0 R` refers to a group object which looks like this:

```
4 0 obj
<</Type/Group
/S/Transparency
/CS/DeviceRGB>>endobj
```

This object defines the page transparency and color space. 
**To get rid of the pdftex warning** it is enough to remove the reference to this group i. e. **remove the line `/Group 4 0 R`** with an editor that won’t hurt the binary data like `vi` or use `sed`:

```
sed -i".bak" -e "/^\/Group 4 0 R$/d" "filename.pdf"
```

For PDFs generated by matplotlibs backend_pdf the group won’t be in a separated group. The main object looks like this:

```
10 0 obj
<< /Group << /CS /DeviceRGB /S /Transparency /Type /Group >> /Parent 2 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 172.8 201.6 ] /Resources 8 0 R /Type /Page /Contents 9 0 R
>>
endobj
```

Here `/Group << /CS /DeviceRGB /S /Transparency /Type /Group >>` has to be removed.

P. S.: The ghostscript method did unfortunately not work for me, the error still appears. Only when I forced PDF version 1.3 in ghostscript it would go away. But that rasterizes the image.

Comment: But it's not an _error_ but a _warning_. Did you read my answer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Yes, I read that but by the time you have about 70 warnings it is simply annoying and I couldn’t see real warnings and errors anymore. Of course this can only be a workaround until a proper solution, probably in pdftex, is found.

Comment: And thanks for the downvote, any explanations? :-/

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question - only the last part, and since the warning is harmless, it's not needed and will probably do more harm then good.

Comment: It would be nice if you could just delete text from a PDF file but you can't -- there are internal pointers that get corrupted.  So this answer is best deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution for Mac users, as the GhostScript color space conversion did not work for me:

Open the file in Mac Preview and save it again (duplicate).

This solved the issue for me with no obvious downsides.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve also created a `qpdf`-based workaround but attempted to make it somewhat more reliable. It’s a shell script `pdfstrippagegroup.sh` that drives a `perl` loop to strip the PDF page group from the temporary QDF file, keeping a bit more state than [Rufflewind’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369352/43807) to avoid accidentally deleting the wrong groups (the `sed`-based answers have this even worse).

#### The script (POSIX sh)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

unset LANGUAGE
LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL

die() {
    echo >&2 "E: ${0##*/}: $dst: $*"
    exit 1
}

for dst in "$@"; do
    tpf=$dst\~.tmp
    tq1=$tpf.1.qdf
    tq2=$tpf.2.qdf
    tq3=$tpf.3.qdf
    tmp=$tpf.pdf
    qpdf --stream-data=uncompress --normalize-content=n --qdf \
        "$dst" "$tq1" || die 'qpdf error converting to QDF'
    # remove PDF page groups (required)
    # also remove Producer info (size improvement)
    perl -e '
        use strict;
        use warnings;

        my $s = "0";
        my $ispage = 0;
        my $gt = "<ERR>";
        while (my $line = <>) {
            my $skip = 0;
            chomp(my $l = $line);
            if ($l eq "<<") {
                $ispage = 0;
                $s = 1 if $s eq 0;
            } elsif ($l eq ">>") {
                if ($s eq 3) {
                    # only omit page groups
                    print $gt unless $ispage;
                }
                $s = 0;
            } elsif ($l eq "  /Type /Page") {
                if (($s == 1) || ($s == 3)) {
                    $ispage = 1;
                }
            } elsif (($s == 1) && ($l eq "  /Group <<")) {
                $gt = $line;
                $s = 2;
                $skip = 1;
            } elsif (($s == 1) && ($l =~ qr`^  /Group `)) {
                $gt = $line;
                $s = 3;
                $skip = 1;
            } elsif ($s == 2) {
                $gt .= $line;
                $s = 3 if $l eq "  >>";
                $skip = 1;
            } elsif ($l eq "trailer <<") {
                $s = 4;
            } elsif ($s == 4) {
                # size optimisation hack
                # remove CreationDate, Producer, etc.
                $skip = 1 if $l =~ qr`^  /Info `;
            }
            print $line unless $skip;
        }
    ' <"$tq1" >"$tq2" || die 'error during perl QDF filtering'
    fix-qdf <"$tq2" >"$tq3" || die 'error during fix-qdf'
    # bullseye first then buster which lacks options
    if ! (set -x; qpdf --stream-data=compress --recompress-flate \
        --compression-level=9 --normalize-content=n \
        --object-streams=disable --deterministic-id \
        "$tq3" "$tmp") 2>"$tq1" && ! (set -x; qpdf \
        --stream-data=compress --normalize-content=n \
        --object-streams=disable --deterministic-id \
        "$tq3" "$tmp") 2>>"$tq1"; then
        cat "$tq1" >&2
        die 'qpdf error converting from QDF'
    fi
    mv "$tmp" "$dst" || die 'could not create target file'
    rm "$tpf"* || die 'error cleaning up tmp QDF files'
    echo >&2 "I: fixed up $dst"
done
echo >&2 "I: done"
```

##### script caveats

The line…

```perl
$skip = 1 if $l =~ qr`^  /Info `;
```

… additionally strips Producer information. Comment it out to retain that, but as it’ll mostly always be just Cairo (for Inkscape) and needlessly take up space, I’m dropping it in our use cases.

#### real-world SVG → PDF conversion

[`svg.ksh`](https://edugit.org/mirabilos/mscore-workshop/-/blob/master/img/svg.ksh) (which uses [`mksh`](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) as scripting shell; for this answer, I converted the above partial script to POSIX sh, but for the full use I prefer this as I also develop mksh which has a few nice safety features) can be used in automated (and not) scenarios to convert SVG images to PDF using Inkscape, cleaning them up with `qpdf` in the same go. We use this in Makefiles that use pdfTₑχ/LᴬTᴇΧ to convert source files to PDF documents in one go.

Comment: You guys are doing some crazy work there.
But is this not insane? Are there no proper solutions to getting SVGs into PDFs in freakin' 2022?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was using the SVG file.
To solve my problem and to automate the process under Microsoft Windows OS I did:

1) Add to the environment variable 'PATH' the full folder paths of Inkscape and Ghostviewer command line executables;

2) You may need to restart the computer, in order to update the environment variable 'PATH' with your changes;

3) Edit a batch file with the following content and name it 'svg2pdf.bat'. Save it in your main folder of the Texniccenter project:

```
@echo off
SET FileName=%1

::Convert forward to backward slash
SET FileName=%FileName:/=\%  

::generate pdf image from svg
inkscape -z -D --file=%FileName%.svg --export-pdf=%FileName%.pdf 
::remove the multiple page problem
gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o %FileName%_aux.pdf %FileName%.pdf  
::save the resultant pdf file
move /y %FileName%_aux.pdf %FileName%.pdf
```

4) In the preamble of the tex file, define the latex commands:

```
\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
        {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0%
        {\immediate\write18{#3}}%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\includesvgpdf}[2][\columnwidth]{%
    \executeiffilenewer{#2.svg}{#2.pdf}{svg2pdf #2}%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2.pdf}%
}
```

This new latex command \includesvgpdf accepts 2 arguments, where the first one must be "width=ToDefine", where "ToDefine" will be the width and the second argument must be the SVG file name without the extension.

Instead of use the command

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{SVG_FILE_NAME}
```

use

```
\includesvgpdf[width=0.5\textwidth]{SVG_FILE_NAME}
```

Hopping it also works for you.

Comment: For me the `gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o %FileName%_aux.pdf %FileName%.pdf` won't remove the warning.