# Is this a bug with Inkscape and/or LaTeX or am I missing something?

Tags: graphics, transparency, svg, inkscape

I want to include figures generated by `inkscape` which include transparency. When I change the width of the figures, things get weird.

Have you ever noticed this and is there a better way to do?

```
% This code works fine
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}

\begin{document}

%\centering
%\def\svgwidth{6cm}
\input{test.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
% This code doesn't
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}

\begin{document}

%\centering
\def\svgwidth{6cm}
\input{test.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a [link](http://www.filedropper.com/archive_73) to the files generated by `inkscape`.

Here is the `TeX` file created by `inkscape`.

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.48.2, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'test.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{476.22402344bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.41427559)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{test.pdf}}%
    \put(0.47641909,0.6172474){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$p\in M$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: I generally just save the image as a `.pdf` in Inkscape and use `\includegraphics{}` and have had no issues.  Is there a reason why you would want to do it this other way?

Comment: If you want your text in the figure to have the same font as elsewhere, you should use this method. I think in my case the problem comes the transparency.

Comment: I tried it with the provided files and for me it works perfectly.

Comment: @bene Did you try also with `\def\svgwidth{6cm}` uncommented?

Comment: of course, have a look here: http://www.uni-ulm.de/~pqa62/tex/inkscape_test.pdf

But I'm wondering, why is there so much space around the figure exported from inkscape? Is it necessary? When I save my figures, I always tell Inkscape only to save the objects without a surrounding frame

Comment: @Bene, when I open your pdf with `preview` (Apple's pdf previewer), I have the same problem ; when I open it with `chrome` it is even worse. When I open it with `photoshop`, it is also bad. This is a link for chating about that (if you have 5 minutes) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11145/latex-and-inkscape?tab=general. I am curious to see a screenshot of the pdf you got.

Comment: @Colas, nice!  This makes sense.  And as for the surrounding frame, can you not just go to `document properties` and `resize to object`?

Comment: @MaxGraves Why does it make sense? The bug seems to happen on `MacOS X` (`preview`, `photoshop` and `chrome`). On `Windows`, the bug is also there on `photoshop`. On http://view.samurajdata.se, on the contrary, it is ok.

Comment: Now, I can produce a bug even without resizing. Transparency seems to create problems...

Comment: I tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78009/8323 but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Colas I meant that it makes sense that one would want to use it to get the same font as in your tex document.