# Can't silence a pdftex "PDF inclusion: multiple PDFs with page group" error

Tags: pdftex, pdf, warnings

I am having an issue with PDFs generatied in `Inkscape`. If multiple files generated in this way are included on a single page I get the following error:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file <FILENAME>.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page>]
```

This seems to be a known bug in `TeX` and has been discussed here:
[Multiple PDFs with page group included in a single page warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76273/multiple-pdfs-with-page-group-included-in-a-single-page-warning)

Rather than running all my PDFs twice through `ghostscript` I would like to address this by using `silence` to surpress the warnings however I am unable to create a warning filter which works.

I have tried `\WarningFilter{pdflatex}{PDF inclusion}` and various permutations however this does not work. I believe this is due to the file name being placed at the start of the error.

The `silence` manual states that it is better to use the `\WarningFilter*` option and to find the process that generates the error message in the `.sty` files. Since pdfTeX is not a package it does not (to the best of my knowledge) have a `.sty` file. I cannot work out which file contains the scripts for generating the errors and thus have not been able to create a function filter.

Does anyone know which file (Windows MiKTeX based distribution) generates these errors or how to make a working filter in this case?

Comment: From the `texlive` root (on Mac), grep finds that `... Binary file **2013/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex** matches ...
Binary file **2013/bin/universal-darwin/pdftex** matches ...`.  Seems like this would be something hard coded into the TeX binary itself, given this.

Comment: It's a _warning_, not an _error_.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198583/post-filtering-output-that-i-cant-seem-to-pre-filter-with-silence-package

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The warning is generated by the binary itself. Since pdfTeX 1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) it can be suppressed by a new primitive:

```
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
```

Quoting the documentation:

> **`\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup`** (integer)
>
> Ordinarily, pdfTeX gives a warning when more than one included pdf
>   file has a so-called "page group object" (`/Group`), because only one
>   can "win" — that is, be propagated to the page level. Usually the page
>   groups are identical, but when they are not, the result is
>   unpredictable. It would be ideal if pdfTeX in fact detected whether
>   the page groups were the same and only gave the warning in the
>   problematic case; unfortunately, this is not easy (a patch would be
>   welcome). Nevertheless, often one observes that there is no actual
>   problem. Then seeing the warnings on every run is just noise, and can
>   be suppressed by setting this parameter to a positive number. The
>   primitive was introduced in pdfTeX 1.40.14.

In the file `NEWS` the version number is 1.40.15, where the primitive is introduced.

Comment: Is it possible to update `MiKTeX 2.9` to use `pdftex 1.40.15`?

Comment: @TomBrien: The [roadmap](http://miktex.org/kb/roadmap-2-9) for MiKTeX 2.9 reveals: "pdf/Xe/Lua TeX engine updates (Summer 2014)"

Comment: Finally marking as accepted since `MiKTeX 2.9` now includes `pdfTeX 1.40.15`

Comment: Seems the quoted documentation is actually incorrect about pdfTeX 1.40.14 and your answer gets it right. This one confirms that 1.40.14 reports undefined control sequence: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310451/25546

Answer (score 1):

I haven't either been able to find a quick answer to this issue.
The following command-line code does not silence the issue, however solve it.
It should be straightforward to understand and is general:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec sed -i '\/Group <</,+5d' {} \;
```

What it does: It recursively searches the current folder for .pdf files.
In these files the entry "/Group <<" is searched. Starting from this line +5 more
, which is the entire Group entry, the lines are deleted.
Problem solved!

Note that for a single, specific file this script would be:

```
find . -name "FILENAME.pdf" -type f -exec sed -i '\/Group <</,+5d' {} \;
```

Best regards

Comment: Internally pdf files work entirely by byte offsets within the file, have you checked if any of those pdfs still work after such an edit (it would be surprising)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right
@felix-schranner This sed statement does work all type of PDF. After doing that, `pdflatex` says `xpdf: reading PDF image failed`