# Where should I specify pdftex primitives?

Tags: pdftex, primitives

I would like to suppress this type of warning by pdftex:

> PDF inclusion: multiple PDFs with page group

So one solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183149/cant-silence-a-pdftex-pdf-inclusion-multiple-pdfs-with-page-group-error) is to use this primitive:

```
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
```

Where should I specify it? In the premable of the .tex document? Or elsewhere?

Comment: preamble would do, but not causing the warning would be better.

Comment: It says `! Undefined control sequence.
l.173 \pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup
                                  =1`

Comment: what version of pdftex do you have I have `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)` and it is defined

Comment: $ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

Comment: as it says in the linked answer you need 1.40.15 and you have 1.40.14