# LaTeX crashes when inserting two figures

Tags: floats, pdftex, subfloats

I have a very strange behaviour of `pdflatex`. I include two files with `figure`. If I include one of the files two times the pdf compiles without any problem. However, if I include both files at the same time, I am getting the following error:

```
PDF inclusion: /Group dict missing
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What can be a reason and in what direction should I search to fix the issue? What derails should I provide to help understanding the issue?

**UPD**
When I insert the same figures in two parts of the text the document does compile, if the figures are included one after another pidflatex crashes.

The figures are included as usually:

```
\input{figure.one}
\input{figure.two}
```

In `figure.*.tex`:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{path/file.pdf}
  \caption{...}
  \label{fig:label}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Hello, how do you include such figures? Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And is your main tex file: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphics} \begin{document} \input{figure.one} \input{figure.two} \end{document}`?  When Moriambar said "starting with" and "ending with", that's what is meant: *everything* we would need to reproduce the error.

Comment: Could it be that `\input{figure.one}` causes the error as the `.one` might be interpreted as a file extension?

Comment: Common guys, do you really think if I add `documentclass` it would help you to reproduce the problem? It is not a standard problem like I can not get a correct spacing or something. If you check my other questions you will see I provide MWE when it is needed. Here it is more about a bug related to `pdflatex` (as it seems from the first googling), and I would like to know if anyone encountered such a behaviour and found out why it happens and how it can be solved. Not everything fit to a common template.

Comment: No dot in the names does not cause this problem. I checked it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple PDFs with page group included in a single page warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76273/multiple-pdfs-with-page-group-included-in-a-single-page-warning)

Comment: I am not sure it is a duplicate as I do not get any warning. `pdflatex` actually crashes. No meaningful message in log is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find WHY it happens, but I found how to fix it. I think there are a problem with metadata stored in one of the PDF files. The problem could be fixed by running **2 times**:

```
gs -o path/figure_fixed.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceRGB path/figure.pdf
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone could provide a more detailed answer and help in understanding what exactly the problem is about.