# pdflatex Fatal error - PDF inclusion: /Group dict missing

Tags: pdfpages

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-last,nup=2x2,landscape=false,frame=true,
            noautoscale=false,delta=0mm 1mm]{handout.pdf}
\end{document}
```

output ends with:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./handout.pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page
>] <handout.pdf, id=159, page=17, 364.19562pt x 273.14648pt>
<use handout.pdf, page 17>
<use handout.pdf, page 17>
<handout.pdf, id=160, page=18, 364.19562pt x 273.14648pt>
<use handout.pdf, page 18>
<use handout.pdf, page 18> <use handout.pdf, page 1>
<use handout.pdf, page 1> <use handout.pdf, page 1>
<use handout.pdf, page 1> <use handout.pdf, page 17>
<use handout.pdf, page 18> [5 <./handout.pdf
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./handout.pdf): PDF inclusion: /Group dict missing
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

what does it mean and how to overcome it? What is /Group dict?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
sources of minimal case:
http://wikisend.com/download/429256/pdflatex-Group_error.zip

```
pdflatex handout.tex
pdflatex handout_2x2.tex
```

(actually it creates 2x1 nup).

My opinion is, that the error comes from severally used pictures. When one picture on page - it's OK, when two pages on single and image on other page already - it's a problem.

Comment: You will have to provide the handout.pdf for tests. Is your texsystem up-to-date?

Comment: please look into zip source in update. The error is quite annoying.

Comment: I get a similar problem when putting 18 slides on a page, but I did not find a solution, except for reducing the number of slides per page and then running pdfnup on the result again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case, I wanted to create a "2-up" pdf from a beamer pdf file (with the command `pdfjam --nup 1x2 my_file.pdf`).

The source of the problem is that several pdf images generated by `inkscape` and `libreoffice` were included in the beamer presentation. This causes `pdftex` and consequently, `pdfjam`, to fail.

There is an active discussion related to having "Page Groups" in PDF in [1] ; but it is not related to `pdfjam` issues. But what they essentially propose is to clean the pdf code.

To my opinion, the proposed cleaning solution are quite cumbersome in [1].
In my case, I just cleaned the pdf file with the following command :

```bash
ps2pdf my_pdfile_buggy.pdf my_file_clean.pdf
```

The generated file `my_file_clean.pdf` can then be processed by `pdfjam`.

---

Tested on

- Ubuntu 20.04
- pdfjam : version 3.03
- gs/ps2pdf : version 9.50

---

[1] [Multiple PDFs with page group included in a single page warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76273/multiple-pdfs-with-page-group-included-in-a-single-page-warning)