# Inserted PNG file gets fainted

Tags: beamer, graphics, png

When I insert PNG file its colors become fainted.
How I can avoid this effect?

The PNG file

[image]

The latex code:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{goal3.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

PDF output (with PdfLatex)

[image]

Comment: Is the `png` file transparent? Perhaps the colour depends on whether you view it on a white background or not?

Comment: It is probably dependent on your pdf viewer. Try and see if SumatraPDF has the same colour. Reader has many settings to try and do fast image processing, but this can lead to different show of colours on screen (perhaps your viewer is set to CPYK colours? Which is not the same as RGB). If I do it with evince, xpdf, I see the "correct" thing.

Comment: I just tried it on my machine and the `png` file looks the same whether I view it separately or as part of your beamer presentation. So it seems to be a viewer issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, you are right it depends on the viewer :(
FoxitPDF renders in original colors.
I played with "page display" and "accessibility" settings in "preferences" in Reader but no success :| 
CMYK / RGB change doesn't affect the colors either.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16061/5763