# pdf graphic produced by Inkscape doesn't print properly

Tags: graphics, pdf, printing, transparency, inkscape

This question was marked as a duplicate:
This question already has an answer here:
[\includegraphics PDF, color problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16061/includegraphics-pdf-color-problem) but I don't see that it is.  I had previously looked at that question, and even tried some of the suggested remedies. But my issue is not with the display (which seems to be the subject of that question) but with the printing. Perhaps I am missing something about the way in which pdf graphics are handled.

Original message:

I am writing a document that has a number of images produced via Inkscape (0.91) and included in my latex document (I'm using TeXshop on a Mac OS 11.5) as pdf files via \includegraphics. These render just fine on screen, but don't print well using various printers; you can see the issue already from printing to a pdf file.

The issue is that regions that have shading or blurring (two effects you can produce in Inkscape) don't print at all.  At the bottom is an example; you can find the graphics file at http://people.brandeis.edu/~ruberman/concordance2.pdf.  If you want to see the native Inkscape .svg version, it's there too: http://people.brandeis.edu/~ruberman/concordance2.svg

Any suggestions on how to handle this? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{concordance2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly how do you print this? The programme is important as not all supports the same features.

Comment: I think it's a PDF and Inkscape relative problem. I've tried to print the PDF, and could reproduce the problem. But it has nothing to do whit Latex or PDFlatex.

Comment: Perhaps ask on the graphic design stackexchange. Here is a related question http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5880/how-can-you-export-an-inkscape-svg-file-to-a-pdf-and-maintain-the-integrity-of-t

Comment: In some viewers, it probably renders wrong. With some print drivers, it probably renders right. Fading etc. are problematic for some viewers/drivers and not others. Even if the image was produced in TeX, the problem would still have nothing to do with TeX - I've seen the problem with TikZ - it is not an Inkscape problem either.

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use? From my experience, transparency and similar often causes trouble with Preview but work fine with Adobe Reader.

Comment: The file displays fine onscreen with any reader: the one built in to TeXshop, Adobe Reader, Preview.  The issue is with the printing; I suppose it could be the driver.  @daleif:I'm printing from the standard Mac dialog from within TeXShop.

Comment: If *printing* is the only issue, that might be off-topic. Perhaps not a duplicate, but still off-topic.

Comment: @Werner I voted to close as off-topic and not as a duplicate. Even if it was a viewer issue, it would almost certainly be off-topic.