# What is the name of the color used in CambridgeUS?

Tags: beamer, color, themes, colortbl

What is the name of the reddish color used in LaTeX beamer CambridgeUS theme?

I would like to use this color in my table using `\cellcolor` command in `colortbl` package.

Answer (score 34):

From [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) you can find [the source of CambridgeUS beamer theme](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeCambridgeUS.sty), where there is:

```
\usecolortheme{beaver}
```

In the same site of the source you can find the [beamer color theme beaver](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemebeaver.sty), where there is:

```
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.8,0,0}
```

I think that's what are you looking for.

Comment: Only one (good) answer is enough (so I erased mine which was similar ;-)).

Comment: Thank you, @PaulGaborit! Indeed I left mine because there are also the links...

Answer (score 6):

You can determine a color in a `tex` document (or, for that matter, a `pdf` or any kind of document) more generally, and use it in your own document by doing the following:

- Have a "color picker"

  - On a `KDE` environment, use [KColorChooser](https://www.kde.org/applications/graphics/kcolorchooser/) for instance,
  - On a Mac, you can use an embedded application, called [DigitalColor Meter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16717/136563),
  - And there are [plenty of open-sources softwares](https://alternativeto.net/software/kcolorchooser/?license=opensource) for every platform.
- Use it to get the `html` code (for instance, `#A30000`),
- load `xcolor` in your preamble,
- define your color using `\definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{A30000}`, cf. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18008/34551).

Comment: Additional note: the color picker could event be a browser add-on, for example.