# How to change background color of the section box in header?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I want to change the color of the box in header containing the sections from white to the color of the word "Outline",  and to change the color of the  name of the sections in this box from red to be the color of the background of the frametitle. This is my current output

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \lstset
 {
 language=[LaTeX]TeX,
 breaklines=true,
 basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
 %commentstyle=\color{green}
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 %stringstyle=\color{black}
 identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}

\title[latex in collaboration]{latex in collaboration}
\author{Alexandre Bernardino}
\institute{ISR/IST}
\date{March 9, 2015}

\AtBeginSection[]
 {
 \begin{frame}<beamer>
 \frametitle{Outline}
 \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
 \end{frame}
 }
 \makeatother
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{.2cm}\scriptsize{\insertshorttitle
 \hspace*{3.5cm} \insertframenumber / \inserttotalframenumber}
 \vspace{4pt}} 
 \makeatletter
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
 \leavevmode%
 \hbox{%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette 
   quaternary}%               
  \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
  }

 \makeatother
 \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
  \titlepage
   \end{frame}

   % Uncomment these lines for an automatically generated outline.
   \begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}
    \section{Some History}
    \section{First Steps}
     \section{\LaTeX{} Basics}

     \end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid the write-up of your objectives isn't exactly clear. Please edit your posting to state more clearly/directly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico I edit the question, hope it is clear now

Comment: For the colour definition, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353963/what-is-the-name-of-the-color-used-in-cambridgeus?newsletter=1&nlcode=212402%7c40b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the colours of the navigation bar with

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
```

The first command changes the colour of the current section and the other sections, the second one the background colour.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
\usecolortheme{beaver} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}

\title[latex in collaboration]{latex in collaboration}
\author{Alexandre Bernardino}
\institute{ISR/IST}
\date{March 9, 2015}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette 
     quaternary}%               
            \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{Some History}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\section{First Steps}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{\LaTeX{} Basics}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want instead of orange, to have  the color of the word "Outline", and instead of the blue to have the color of the background of the frametitle. In other word to reverse the colors of the navigation bar and the frametitle

Comment: @FarahMind please see my edit

Comment: Thank you for you update. I think the colors are not the same, can't we get the exact colors used in the template

Comment: @FarahMind Its the exact colour from beaver colour theme.

Comment: ok, now th problem is the current section, it is not highlighted in the navigation bar

Comment: @FarahMind "The first command changes the colour of the current section and the other sections" -> Change one of the two colours