# Bookmarks do not work with PDF/X

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, pdfx

It seems bookmarks do not work, when PDF/X is used. For example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x-302]{pdfx}
\hypersetup{final}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Section}
asdf
\chapter{Another Section}
asdf
\end{document}
```

This tex does not produce pdf bookmarks for the sections. Changing from x-302 to a-1b, however, will produce bookmarks as expected.

How can I get bookmarks with PDF/X formats?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) isn't PDF/X a graphics change specification, thus bookmarks does not really make any sense. (3) looking in the `pdfx` code. The `pdfx` switch (enabled by `x-302`) explicitly sets `bookmarks=false` in `\hypersetup`. You might get away with just setting `\hypersetup{bookmarks=true}` (untested)

Comment: Thanks :) I do not really know details about the intended usage of pdf/x, but afaik it's supposed to be used for printing documents. Bookmarks are not necessary for printing, but it seems more convenient to me to have only one pdf for reading on the computer and printing.

Comment: The bookmarks=true does not seem to work, but thanks for the hint that bookmarks=false is set by the package. Seems it's not possible to do that due to the specifications of pdf/x

Comment: That I think might be an hyperref issue, see the log, there is a warning about `bookmarks` having already been set.

Comment: Hmm, strange I cannot even use `\hypersetup{bookmarks=true}` in a simple `hyperref` doc (no `pdfx`)

Comment: As far as i know bookmarks and other annotations are restricted in PDF/X standards. So, may be it will suit you to stick to PDF/A standards.
You can try to produce PDF/A with additional PDF/X restrictions manually: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349521/79756

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks are technically actions of type `GoTo`. Actions are forbidden in PDF/X- up to 5 because they cannot be printed. I agree this is inconvenient when you want *one* pdf for printing and screen. Maybe this will change with upcoming PDF/X-6.

In the meanwhile you can [create a document with hyperlinks that declares being PDF/X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536060/50129). It will throw a validation error in Acrobat Preflight but someone knowledgeable in a print shop will not take this seriously.