# How to specify a FOGRA39 ICC colour profile in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, printing, color-profile

I found some posts about this (like [pdfx: CMYK color profile in PDF/A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464079/pdfx-cmyk-color-profile-in-pdf-a)) but I'm not sure it applies to my case.

Here is the context :

1. I'm a designer and I'm working on a mixed Adobe/LaTeX workflow
2. I intend to produce the aesthetics in Adobe Illustrator and insert them as pdf background (I found this topic : [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278620/how-to-insert-a-pdf-as-ba~~kground](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278620/how-to-insert-a-pdf-as-ba%7E%7Ekground)).
3. The text is to be parsed by LuaLaTeX from a .csv file (this part is managed so far) so it will appear on top of the graphics.
4. **I need a Fogra39 (iso coated V2) colour profile for the printing compagny I'm working with**

Background pdf graphics  will be output in CMYK Fogra39 but I don't know how to ensure that the final output LaTeX will give me will be also in Fogra39.

Any idea ?

Comment: there is a `FOGRA39L_coated.icc` in tex/generic/colorprofiles. If this okay you can embed it more or less along the tips in your first links.

Comment: Considered you are a professional I really recommend reading a book about colour management or let it explain to you by your preferred printer. FOGRA39 and  ISO coated v2 are different. Which one do you need? After all, both are outdated. Use FOGRA 51 for PS 1 paper FOGRA 50 for PT1 paper or FOGRA 52 for PS 5 paper. My [answer to the first question you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536060/50129) tells you how to embed a profile. What do you need more?