# LaTeX for printing press

Tags: printing, big-list, tutorials

This is a general question aimed at being a comprehensive tutorial and/or a Getting started guide.

***My intent** is to create a workflow that is independent of InDesign/Scribus etc.*

*Of course, the printers themselves mostly use proprietary software which is beyond my circle of influence.*

I couldn't find much information in TeX.SE about preparing the LaTeX output in a way that is required by the printer. Hence I have asked it here.

**1. How to create a pre-press PDF file?**

**2. What are the different packages that are involved that one should know to produce a press-ready PDF file?**

**3. I need some pointers/resource materials so that I can get familiarised with the terminologies used by the printers.**

For example, there are terms like bleeds, crop marks etc. which refer broadly to the extra space and marks required for the printers to be able to cut and bind a book/magazine etc.

Regards.

Comment: You might get more help if you describe the extra features you need and then ask which packages would be useful to know about. At the moment, I would need to know about printing and binding to answer your question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Yes. This question is aimed at those who are familiar with the book production workflow — from layout design and typesetting to getting the book in print.

Comment: I suggest you google for "bleed(s)" and "crop marks", etc. You might, or might not, find Derek Brown, "Designing a Book" ,Primrose Hill Press, 2003, ISBN 1 901648 33 8 useful.

Comment: @PeterWilson Thanks a lot! Having a hard time finding the book, though!

Comment: Look up The Printing of Mathematics.

Comment: You may also have a look at publishers websites, inviting users submissions, like journals, magazines, books may be. Those usually provide input formats of various kinds. Also self-publishing as print may describe workflows in more detail.

Comment: `pdfx` package allows to create a pdf-x file, which should comply with a number of requirements for press. It includes function to manage color profiles (cf. https://ctan.org/pkg/colorprofiles), which is perhaps one of the most tricky aspects... For crop marks, see `crop` package. On colors, cf. also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61217/latex-color-and-icc-color-profiles.

Comment: @lacobus1983 . That was very useful!

Comment: @PeterWilson Can you help me in getting the book, “Designing a Book” by Derek Brown?

Comment: I can't help you in getting a book. Another one you might find useful is Ruari McLean "The Thames and Hudson Manual of Typography",  Thames and Hudson, 1980,