# PDFLaTeX Color Space

Tags: pdftex, color, acrobat

## Background

Am using TeX Live 2012, pdflatex, and latexmk to produce the document, on Ubuntu Linux.

## Problem

In the following image, Okular is shown on the left and Adobe Acrobat Reader is shown on the right.

[image: Okular vs Acrobat Reader]

The images in the document most likely contain various colour spaces. The colours in Okular are desired (and shown as coded in the LaTeX); whereas, the colours in Acrobat Reader are not desired.

I have read a few different questions on this topic, including:

- [PDF colour model and LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/pdf-colour-model-and-latex)

## Question

What is most likely the problem with the colours in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and how should I resolve it?

## Ideas

I was thinking that the problem might be caused by having images in multiple color spaces. If that's the case, then I could resolve it by running the images through ImageMagick.

The alternative is to use `xcolor`, as suggested.

Comment: Why do you think that Okular (rather than Adobe) handles everything correctly?

Comment: perhaps this answer helps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/using-opacity-in-tikz-causes-strange-rendering-in-acrobat/9266#9266

Comment: Are you on a Linux machine? I found that the Linux version of the Acrobat Reader shows ugly colours for figures generated by R and RTikzDevice. The colours are fine in okular and in the Windows version of the Reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines were added to the preamble:

```
\RequirePackage[xcolornames,svgnames,dvipsnames,rgb]{xcolor}
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

This seems to have resolved the problem.