# Why output of dvipdfmx looks better than output of pdftex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, ps2pdf, dvipdfmx, type1

When viewed on screen, look of document processed via `dvipdfmx` is better, than that of produced via `pdftex`.

This happens with absolutely any document, even with plain format.

I tried with these viewers:

> atril xpdf evince qpdfview mupdf okular gv zathura

Each of them produces different screen output on documents, obtained via `dvipdfmx` (or `dvips+ps2pdf`) and `pdftex`.

As is shown on the pictures, in pdf mode the font color is grey and links color is blurry, in comparison with dvi mode.

[image][pdftex.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxmd5m7mckfnbzd/pdf.pdf?dl=0)
[image][dvipdfmx.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qgp5fjkakqbiwn/dvi.pdf?dl=0)

```
$ pdffonts dvi.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
FESNVM+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes yes      4  0
XZXPQO+CMR10                         Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
CSTOKE+CMR8                          Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
LXXLBC+CMBX10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
LIFJYF+CMTI10                        Type 1C           Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
```

```
$ pdffonts pdf.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IGWWSQ+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
GVEKFU+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
JBEWTB+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      10  0
RRATMA+CMBX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
YOSONK+CMTI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      14  0
```

In one of the topics it was proposed to convert Type1 fonts to Type1C fonts via `ps2pdf`, but the problem is that `ps2pdf` converts fonts to raster images while creating pdf, thus this is not a proper way. Moreover, although the converted document is better, it is still a little blurry in comparison with the one, obtained via `dvipdfmx`.

I will accept if this is not possible to correct pdf viewer or pdftex, but at least *why* do not I get the same look of the document from `pdftex` and `dvipdfmx`?

*NOTE* the answer should not assume changing fonts - default Computer Modern must be used.

**UPDATE**

This is very strange: compile the following code with `pdftex` and `tex+dvipdfmx` - the colors are not the same at all! Maybe this is the key for understanding this mystery?

1) code for dvipdfmx:

```
\special{color push rgb 0 0 1}
\vrule width 5cm height 5cm
\special{color pop}
\bye
```

2) code for pdftex:

```
\input pdfcolor
\Blue
\vrule width 5cm height 5cm
\bye
```

[image][dvi mode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a27mzctlz4hqer1/dvipdfmx-color.pdf?dl=0)
[image][pdf mode](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f001drap1k6r3z/pdftex-color.pdf?dl=0)

And the same for `\Black` !!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: What font info is reported for the two docs?

Comment: I think, in your case, pdftex uses a different
color model compared with the dvi mode.
Please see messages carefully. Maybe `pdfcolor.tex`
or something is read in the case of pdftex, while
it is not read in the dvi mode.

Comment: using  `\input color \color{blue}` rather than `\input pdfcolor \Blue` produces correct color.

Comment: I am sure David will explain what's wrong with `\def\cmykBlue{1 1 0 0}\def\Blue{\pdfsetcolor{\cmykBlue}}` from `pdfcolor`... (and `\def\pdfsetcolor#1{\pdfliteral{#1 k}}`). Actually perhaps nothing wrong, but simply `\Blue` cmyk specification happens to produce a violet like colour.

Comment: hmm, according to http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.htm, it is correct to specify `1 1 0 0` in cmyk model as corresponding to `0 0 255` in rgb model.

Comment: but `\input color \color[cmyk]{1,1,0,0}` produces the violet thing. And one sees the same with LaTeX source ``\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\color[cmyk]{1,1,0,0}
\rule {5cm}{5cm}
\end{document}``. I presume there is an obvious missing thing in my code, hence this comment will auto-destruct once I am enlightened.

Comment: In `LaTeX` you can use `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[rgb]{xcolor} \begin{document} \color[cmyk]{1,1,0,0} \rule {5cm}{5cm} \end{document}` to produce the same output as with `\color{blue}`. The `rgb` option to `xcolor` tells it  to convert the color to `rgb`-model. I believe this means the `pdf` is then created with something akin to `\pdfliteral {0 0 1 rg 0 0 1 RG}` (apart from using the pdf color stack). I don't know why using a `\pdfliteral` color specification in `cmyk` model seems to result in a very different color space at the time of pdf rendering.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973/4686) will prove useful ? what I understand is that the `\Blue` in `pdfcolor.tex` is in an abstract `cmyk` model, whose naive conversion to `rgb` model does correspond to `R0 G0 B255`, this is for example what `xcolor` would do if asked to do that conversion `cmyk->rgb`;  but if one lets the `cmyk` color spec inscribed as is inside the `pdf` it will end up rendered very differently than the supposedly equivalent `rgb spec`. Other (non-linear ?) conversions are done [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

Comment: As I said first, you are comparing different colors.
Please try
`%tex + dvipdfmx`
`\input color`
`\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0,0,1}`
`\definecolor{Myblue}{cmyk}{1,1,0,0}`
`\color{myblue}`
`\vrule width 5cm height 5cm`
`\color{Myblue}`
`\hskip5mm\vrule width 5cm height 5cm`
`\bye`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337122/48 (about the Type 1 vs Type 1C)

Answer (score 3):

There were actually two clashing problems, which in the beginning I thought was one problem - and as such messed up some points in my question.

In light of newly revealed facts, I would like reclassify the above mentioned viewers into two categories.

a) the following viewers differ only with respect to color model (rgb vs. cmyk)

> gv mupdf

b) the following viewers differ with respect to color model and with respect to fonts handling (Type1 vs. Type1C)

> qpdfview evince okular xpdf atril zathura

1) Answer for the problem with color model:

use `\pdfliteral{0 0 1 rg}` and `\pdfliteral{0 0 0 rg}` for blue and black correspondingly

2) Answer for the problem with greyish look: convert the document with `ps2pdf` (it does not produce raster fonts, as I mistakenly wrote in my question)

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true orig.pdf new.pdf
```

Now when I compare output of ps2pdf with output of dvipdfmx there are any differences.

The only thing left to do is to ensure that this ps2pdf command works without loss of information, i.e., how to convert back to Type1 fonts and compare hash sums with the original?

Summary: Apart from the problem with color model, I presume this to be a bug of pdf viewer and/or pdf library in handling Type1 fonts vs. Type1C fonts, because output of `gv` and `mupdf` looks absolutely the same before and after processing with `ps2pdf`, as it should be.