# Duotone pdf for printing?

Tags: xetex, pdf, printing

I want my document to have only two colors (using CMYK). Let's say black and Cyan. For the Cyan I want to have a tint. Will the following code work or the printshop will tell me that these are more than two colors? (using XelaTeX)

```
 \definecolor{vividcolor}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
 \definecolor{simplecolor}{cmyk}{0.5,0,0,0}
```

Comment: I assume your output format is PDF? Please, take a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9973/13450 and here tex.stackexchange.com/a/99666/13450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be fine. Both colours will appear on a single plate (CYAN) --- the first as a solid, the second as a 50% screen.